# Create a helper or something for haml with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am using haml with my rails application and i have a question how the easiest way to insert this haml code into a html file:

```
<div clas="holder">
 <div class=top"></div>
  <div class="content">
   Content into the div goes here
  </div>
 <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

And I want to use it in my haml document like this:

```
%html
 %head
 %body
  Maybee some content here.
  %content_box #I want to get the code i wrote inserted here
   Content that goes in the content_box like news or stuff
 %body
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

---

I get this error:

```
**unexpected $end, expecting kEND**
```

with this code:

```
# Methods added to this helper will be available to all templates in the application.
module ApplicationHelper
 def content_box(&block)
  open :div, :class => "holder" do # haml helper
   open :div, :class => "top"
    open :div, :class => "content" do
      block.call
    open :div, :class => "bottom"
  end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use haml_tag too

```
def content_box
  haml_tag :div, :class => "holder" do
    haml_tag :div, :class => "top"
    haml_tag :div, :class => "content" do
      yield
    haml_tag :div, :class => "bottom"
  end
end
```

and in haml

```
%html
  %head
  %body
    Maybee some content here.
    = content_box do
      Content that goes in the content_box like news or stuff
```

Comment: please read my comment on the other answer. and which one is the most effective in terms of speed of the application?

Comment: the difference of speed is really nul. The helper method is great to use it.

Answer (score 3):

The typical solution to this is to use a partial.

Or a helper method in your _helper.rb file:

```
def content_box(&block)
  open :div, :class => "holder" do # haml helper
    open :div, :class => "top"
    open :div, :class => "content" do
      block.call
    end
    open :div, :class => "bottom"
  end
end
```

And in haml:

```
%html
  %head
  %body
    Maybee some content here.
    = content_box do
      Content that goes in the content_box like news or stuff
```

Comment: ok, thanks. and where do i put the _helper.rb and how do i load it?
sorry im new to rails. just been using PHP

Comment: and i want to send a parameter to the function for changing the color of the box, and it works like changing the class on the div from class="holder_@color_here", how can i do that?

Comment: The `open` method has been replaced with `haml_tag` for several versions. Use `haml_tag` instead.

If you want the helper to be available anywhere in the application, put it in app/helpers/application.rb. If you only want it to be available to views for FoosController, put it in app/helpers/foos.rb.

Comment: It's been a while since I last used haml, or rails... =(
But good work on haml there nex3!